# What WebTemplates are available for site designs in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, spo, sp-online, site-design

Reading Microsoft Documentation for the command `Add-SPOSiteDesign`, I see three potential values of the `WebTemplate` parameter are 1 (team site not connected to group), 64 (team site), and 68 (communication site). Out of curiosity, what are the other values? I have not found any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Site Template ID – Microsoft Office 365 for your reference:

https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-online-site-template-id

SharePoint Online Site Template ID list for PowerShell for your reference:

https://vladtalkstech.com/2019/12/sharepoint-online-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html

Comment: Thank you, the first link was what I needed.